# POST method sends no data to Django function based views

Tags: django

I have been trying to write a function based delete view:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from ttt import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('delete_task/<str:pk>/', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
def delete_task(request, pk):

    task_details = Task.objects.get(id=pk)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_details.delete()
        return redirect('/')


    context={
        'task_details' : task_details
        }

    return render(request, 'ttt/delete_task.html', context)
```

delete_task.html

```
    <form action = "#"  method="POST">
{% csrf_token%}

<input type="submit" name="Confirm Delete"></input>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" >Cancel</a>

</form>
```

When I submit the delete form, I am redirected to an error page. In python shell, I can see the POST data is empty when I select 'Confirm Delete'(this should be passing the id of the task I want to delete).

The error I am gett
ing is :

```
    NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'view_task' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view_task/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Also, my models.py :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.



class Member(models.Model):
    DESIGNATION = [
        ('Developer', 'Developer'),
        ('Tester', 'Tester'),
        ('Support', 'Support'),
        ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=DESIGNATION)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Task(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
        ( 'Low', 'Low'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Urgent', 'Urgent'),
        ]

    STATUS = [
        ('Not Started', 'Not Started'),
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ]
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    task_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name





class Allocation(models.Model):
    
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    task = models.OneToOneField('Task', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member.name
```

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /` meaning you are properly redirected to the url `/`. The error you get is likely unrelated to this `delete_task` view. You need to look at the view `home` and it's template.

Comment: You are not passing any `pk` value in your delete_task.html

Comment: Also change your `action="#"` to `action="{% url 'delete_task' %}"` and pass the `pk` value, problem will get fixed.

Comment: If you are using a form, then there is no need to pass the pk through the url, just pass it through the post request.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got the issue fixed. I just changed ```task = models.OneToOneField('Task', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) to ask = models.OneToOneField('Task', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE.```